# Usando o Navigate para carregar mais de um link no WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Como fazer o `Navigate` ir para o próximo link após o primeiro ter carregado? Já tentei algumas coisas mas não obtive sucesso.

```
nomedobrowser.Navigate("http://reidocrime.com/");
nomedobrowser.Navigate("http://reidocrime.com/map/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça isso no evento [`DocumentCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), ele ocorre quando o `WebBrowser` termina de carregar um documento.

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser1.Navigate("http://reidocrime.com/map/");
}
```

Comment: para o que eu quero isso não me tem serventia,não a outra maneira?

Comment: estou fazendo um bot para um jogo e ele é a base de links, gostaria que ele abrisse um link apos o outro, e assim fazer um loop